LDAP Directory/attribute endpoint not consistent
I am getting an error while using the /api/v2/Directory/attribute?AttributeName.GeneralQuery-62379-85221-PROD", for that specify the AttributeName=member, Domain=AD and DistinguishedName=CN=GeneralQuery-62379-85221-PROD,OU=LDAPRoles,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=ad,DC=jpmorganchase,DC=com as shown below:
I am getting 200 for some of the AD groups but some are returning this error {
"date": "2024-05-08",
"status": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": [ "Failed to find ldap object with dn: CN=UAD_CBCatalyst_MM_FSG_Northeast-103580-PROD,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=AD,DC=JPMORGANCHASE,DC=com in domain: AD;org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310028C, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:\n\t'OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=AD,DC=JPMORGANCHASE,DC=com'\n
When I use
/api/v2/Directory?AttributeList=distinguishedName, member, mail&Domain=AD&FilterAttribute=CN&FilterOperator=EQUALS&FilterValue
I am getting 200 for the abvove AD  but my issue is I do not want to make different api call for different AD group if it's complaing because of Filtervalues.
